# FilteredRowSet Predicate evaluate method

Tags: java, jdbc

When I create a `Predicate` object I don't understand when the last two methods
are called...

```
class My_Filter implements Predicate
{
    public boolean evaluate(RowSet rs)
    {
    }

    public boolean evaluate(Object value, int column) throws SQLException
    {
    }

    public boolean evaluate(Object value, String columnName) throws SQLException
    {
    }
}
```

in my simple example they are never called.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if your example includes inserting rows. According to the java doc for both the column based evaluate methods ...

> The FilteredRowSet object will use
>   this method internally while inserting
>   new rows to a FilteredRowSet instance.